# how to tell crontab to execute the command from now instantly

Tags: cron, scheduling

I have a command in "/etc/crontab" which runs a database program every 7 days. Now, I see that this command has been commented by another user for 2 weeks. I immediately uncommented the line, and today I see that this command has not been executed by crontab.

Why? I think after restarting /etc/init.d/cron restart, crontab would restart and see the command line, which says to execute a command every 7 days. Then when is it going to start that program! isn't it immediately at the start of service crond restarting? it seems not.

I cannot wait 7 days for the program now, I want crontab to start the this 7 days from tonight. how can I do that?

the script is:

```
0 0 */7 * *        root  source /opt/db_maintain/run.sh
```

Comment: Do you want the crontab to execute the script right now? Or today at midnight?

Comment: You know, an "edit war" as root user on a system is a very very bad idea. Can your script/database run as a non-root user? If so, you can have _your own_ crontab file!

Answer (score 2):

*/7 doesn't mean "every 7 days from now". It means "every days that are a multiple of 7". So it runs the command if #day modulo 7 == 0 →
7th, 14th, 21st, 28th of the month.

The french wiki page of Cron provides many examples:
http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Exemples

You may want to use Fcron:
http://fcron.free.fr/

Answer (score 1):

Today is Wednesday. If you want cron to execute a command at midnight every Thursday, here's what you put in your crontab:

```
0 0 * * 4    root /path/to/command
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also install the `at` service/daemon which spools jobs based on time features like "now + 7 days".  First, launch `atd` (through the `init` scripts or `systemd` or `upstart` etc). Then queue up your job with

```
at -f /path/to/command now + 7 days
```

to start it 7 days from right now, or

```
at 2am tomorrow
```

and read the commands to be run tomorrow at 2 in the morning. You'll want to do a test or two before waiting 7 days to find it didn't work. Try `now + 1 minutes`

One way to have it run every 7 days is to prepend the batch with another `at` command:

```
cat >~/bin/weekly-job.sh << AT
at -f ~/bin/weekly-job.sh now + 7 days
~/bin/database-job.sh
AT
```